# OracleManaged.DataAcess Result in ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

My application c# connect to oralce using OracleManagedDataAcess.

In developer enviroment, he can be resolve tnsnames.ora, but, when try run in another machine, he launch this error: `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

My TNSNAMES.ora is in `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\`

I have Environment variable TNS_ADMIN pointing out for `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\`

My App.config is:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">         
      <settings>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

String connection is : `cnx_str = String.Format("Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={1};Password={2}", dataSource, username, password);`

I need connect to Oracle using the config in TNSNAMES.ora. Why OracleManagedDataAccess can not resolve TNS ? 
I see many answers about this problem, but none resolve for me.

Comment: Drivers for oracle are installed on that machine?

Comment: Yes, All machines have client oracle installed

Comment: Is the client installed in the same path on the other machines? And can the other machines connect to the server with `sqlplus` or `tnsping`?

Comment: Yes, sorry not mentionar, TNSPING works

Comment: I just tried connect without useTNSNAMES, but the error persist

Comment: What version is the database? Also 10.2?

Comment: If you get an error even without an alias then you have most likely a typo in your connection string.

Comment: @nilsK ODP.NET **Managed Driver** does not need any further installation of an Oracle client.

Comment: After many work, i Discovery the problem. It is in sqlnet.ora
of: `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES)` for 

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)`